# Using dependency properties

Tags: xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I have I very simple WPF game:
It has a couple of buttons and some labels.
Every time the user clicks on a button I have a counter that I raise by 1.
I want to show to counter value on every label on my window, and I want to do so using the XAML, not by code behind.
How do I do this using dependency property and / or binding?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `DependencyProperty` for this, it is a very simple DataBinding scenario.  I would highly recommend using the MVVM design pattern, since this is the recommended approach for WPF.

You will need to create a ViewModel that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a 
Counter Property.  This property will raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` from the Setter to notify DataBinding Targets that the value has been updated.

You can use a `Command` that is bound to the `Button` which will increment the Counter property on the ViewModel.  The Command will be exposed as a Property in your ViewModel as well.

And the Label(s) will be databound to the Counter property so that when they property value changes, they are automatically updated.

For specifics and code examples, I would suggest reading up on WPF & MVVM from one of the many resources available.  One of my favorites is the [Prism Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx), or specifically, the [MVVM section of the Prism Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).  Prism also contains base classes which can simplify this whole process.

If you choose not to go with Prism, there are many alternative MVVM frameworks and intros available, just do a search.

Comment: Could you show me what I have to do, instead of going to MVVM model?